# Push Notification on iPhone error

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I worked on push notifications and everything was going well, but when I reached this step of the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1):

> At this point it’s a good idea to test whether the certificate works. Execute the following command:

```
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.232.226...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I executed this command, but I don't get connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't connect?

Comment: What is the problem? Seems like you connected to sandbox push server.

Comment: please check .pem file

Comment: `Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net`, but you say *"I don't get connected"*. It looks like you **did** connect. What problem are you trying to solve?